# empty Shared Preferences cause my App to crash

Tags: java, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I am working on my first app and have a problem with my shared preferences.
The app i am trying to build is a financal planer to insert monthly expenses and income to check how much money is left at the end of a month.

When my shared preferences have a value, i.e. by starting the app with the troublesome code commented out and leaving the inserted value saved, the app works perfectly.

However, as soon as I delete the input or start the app from very scratch without anything saved it stops working.

```
// Setting up shared preferences
FinancePlanPreferences = getSharedPreferences("FinancePlan", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String netIncomeAmount = 
FinancePlanPreferences.getString("netIncomeAmount", "");

// Setting up EditText
netIncomeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.netIncomeInput);


//here I tried to workaround the problem
        if (netIncomeInput.equals("")) {
       netIncomeInput.setText("0,00");
    } else {netIncomeInput.setText(FinancePlanPreferences.getString("netIncomeAmount",""));

// receive the Input 
String netIncomeAmount = netIncomeInput.getText().toString();

// store Input in shared preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = FinancePlanPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("netIncomeAmount", netIncomeAmount);
editor.apply();

// and this line causes the problem. it works when there is a value saved. (p.s. the replace part is since the numbers are inserted in the german format)
netIncomeAmountTextView.setText(FinancePlanPreferences.getString("netIncomeAmount", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors (at least a missing curly bracket), if it actually compiles, please copy and paste the real code instead of transcripting it.

Comment: the curly brackets aren't the problem. the code compiles. the real code would be very, very large ...

Comment: Well it is a problem on this side of the table because the code is harder to understand.

Comment: The error it gives me is the following:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.financearchitect/com.example.financearchitect.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Bad offset/length: offset=0 len=0 in.length=0  and Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Bad offset/length: offset=0 len=0 in.length=0

Comment: NumberFormatException ussually points at a conversion form String to int, float, or double which can't be converted due to the String not representing a number. The error also references a line number. Make sure you have included that code in the question. Also checkout `if (netIncomeInput.equals("")) ` I think you really meant `if (netIncomeInput == null) ` or `if (netIncomeInput.getText().toString().equals("")) `